# c# method overload picks the wrong overload and compiles

Tags: c#, overloading

I have the following:

```
EnErrorCodes WriteToCard(EnRegs address, byte data)
EnErrorCodes WriteToCard(EnRegs address, ushort data)
EnErrorCodes WriteToCard(EnRegs address, uint data)
EnErrorCodes WriteToCard(EnRegs address, float data)
EnErrorCodes WriteToCard(EnRegs address, double data)
```

but had missed the `ulong` overload.

When then using the overloads blindly with a `ulong`, the compiler picked the `float` overload rather than throwing an error.

Took ages to work out why the system wasn't writing that data properly, only ctrl+clicking on the `WriteToCard` method where it was called then took it to the float overload.

Creating the `ulong` one obviously sorted it but I don't understand why it happened as it was a rather annoying feature to try and find.

Comment: ulong can be implicitly converted to float: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions

Answer (score 3):

This is because of [`Implicit` numeric conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#implicit-numeric-conversions).

[image]

If you look at highlighted part of above image, C# converts `ulong` to `float`, `double`, `decimal`.

As you have `WriteToCard()` with `float` parameter, if you pass `data` with `ulong` as a type, compiler implictly converts it to float and execute it, instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 3):

`ulong` can be [implicitly converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions) to `float` and `double`, so there are two valid candidates for [selecting method overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#method-invocations). The `float` one is selected because it is [better conversion target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-conversion-target):

> Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target than T2 if no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists, and at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists
> - ...

So there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `float`, but there is one from `float` to `double`